# What is the difference between Worker Role and Worker Role with Service Bus Queue

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

What is the difference between these two implementations, can someone tell which one is to use under what scenario?

Also pros and cons if there is any? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't really any difference between the two. Worker role with Service Bus Queue is just a VS project template that adds the Service Bus dependencies and configures an empty message handling function and adds the code ready to set up your own connection string etc.
If you are planning on implementing a worker role that reads from a queue it will save you a little typing time. If you prefer you can create a basic Worker Role project and add queue handling logic to it, you will ultimately achieve the same thing.

Comment: one little clarification if you can add plz, is there any other way to access queue as well apart from service bus using worker role?

Comment: The actual difference is between Azure Queue and Service Queue. Worker Role with Service Bus Queue gives out of the box implementation for Service Bus Queue which is different that Azure Queue.

Comment: Worker Role is an empty worker to which you can add any logic you wish including reading from Azure Queue. Worker Role with Service Bus Queue is a Worker Role with the plumbing for reading from the service bus (I should have made clearer I meant service bus queue in my answer). There's a sample application using a worker role and Azure Queue here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-get-started/